# Access to short diagonal elements in Numpy 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, diagonal

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array and I want to access short diagonal elements of it. Let's say i,j,k are three dimensions. Is it possible to access elements where `i==j` **or** `i==k` **or** `j==k`, so that I can set them to a specific value.

I tried to solve this by creating a mask variable of indices. This mask variable of indices is fed to the final array where the values of `{i=j or i=k or j=k}` are set to specific values. Unfortunately this code is returning the set where `{i=j=k}`

```
import numpy as np

N = 3

maskXY = np.eye(N).reshape(N,N,1)

maskYZ = np.eye(N).reshape(1,N,N)

maskXZ = np.eye(N).reshape(N,1,N)

maskIndices = maskXY * maskYZ*maskXZ

#set the values of final array using above mask

finalArray[maskIndices] = #specific values
```

Comment: Since you want `or` and not `and`, I think you need to add, not multiply: `maskIndices = maskXY + maskYZ + maskXZ`. You can also clip the values at 1 after using `np.clip()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could create open meshes with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) using the ranged arrays covering the dimensions of the input array and then perform OR-ing among those with a very close syntax to the one described in the question, like so -

```
i,j,k = np.ix_(*[np.arange(r) for r in finalArray.shape])
mask = (i==j) | (i==k) | (j==k)
finalArray[mask] = # desired values
```

**Approach #2**

It seems, we can also follow the posted code in the question and use boolean versions of the masks and then perform OR-ing to get the `mask` equivalent, like so -

```
mask = (maskXY==1) | (maskYZ==1) | (maskXZ==1)
```

But, this involves masks that are 2D (when squeezed) and as such won't be as memory-efficient as the previous approach that dealt with 1D arrays.